# How should i convert the scriptlet to JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
 <A HREF='<%=urlProfile%>'><%=objUserDetailsVO.getLogin_Ident()%></TD>
      <%if(objUserDetailsVO.getFlgBifNonBif().trim().equals("Y")){
       nonBifFlag="*";
       }    
    %>
```

Comment: UserDetailsVO objUserDetailsVO = null;

Comment: It is an object for the class UserDetailsVO.It has been initialized as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `objUserDetailsVO` in request/session/page/application context that is available to this jsp. (choose the scope that is most suitable here),

Now

```
<A HREF='${urlProfile}'${objUserDetailsVO.login_Ident}'/></TD>

<c:if test="${objUserDetailsVO.flgBifNonBif=='Y'>
       <c:set var="nonBifFlag" value="*"/>
</c:if>
```

**Note:**

You need `urlProfile` & `objUserDetailsVO`  available to JSP as mentioned above.

**Update:** (on your new Question)

```
<c:if test="${empty NONBIFUPDATEMODE}">
    NONBIFUPDATEMODE is empty or null.
</c:if>
```

Comment: <%=objUserDetailsVO.getLogin_Ident()%> can be written as <c:out value="${objUserDetailsVO.getName}"/>

Comment: `<c:out value="${objUserDetailsVO.name}"/>`

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) , and you forgot to accept this answer

Comment: How to use session inside the if condition

Comment: when you write `${NONBIFUPDATEMODE}` it will invoke check in page,request,session,applicatoin context and it will resolve it

Comment: Then <c:set var="nonBifupdate" value="${sessionScope['NONBIFUPDATEMODE']}"/> not needed

Comment: **No** <!------------------->